# Pass A Value From Last Page And Auto Selected On The Dropdown List PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a project using PHP. Passed two parameters from previousp page to page `Update.php`:

```
$ID = $_GET['PosterId'] 
$catID = $_GET['CategoryID'];
```

On `Update.php`, a dropdown lists all categories retrieved from category table.

```
$sql = "SELECT PosterID, CategoryID, Category, Title, Price FROM tblposters where PosterID =" . $ID;    
$sqlCategory = "select  CategoryID, CategoryName from tblcategory";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCategory);
$resultCategory = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCategory);

// get category list from table
echo "<select id='Category' name='CategoryList'>";
echo "<option value='-1'>Please Select Posters Group</option>";

while( $row =  $resultCategory -> fetch_assoc( )) {     
    $catRowID = $row['CategoryID'];
    $cat = $row['CategoryName'];
    echo "<option value='$catRowID'> $cat </option>";
}

echo "</select></div>"; 
?>
```

Since the categoryID for this PosterID has been passed to this page, I want to display it's categoryname by default in the dropdown. How could I write the code with PHP on the `<option>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT PosterID, CategoryID, Category, Title, Price FROM tblposters where PosterID =" . $ID;    
$sqlCategory = "select  CategoryID, CategoryName from tblcategory";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCategory);
$resultCategory = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCategory);

//get category list from table
echo "<select id='Category' name='CategoryList'>";
echo "<option value='-1'>Please Select Posters Group</option>";
while( $row =  $resultCategory -> fetch_assoc( )){  
$catRowID = $row['CategoryID'];
$cat = $row['CategoryName'];
if($_GET['CategoryID'] == $row['CategoryID'])
{
echo "<option value='$catRowID' selected> $cat </option>";
}
else
{
echo "<option value='$catRowID'> $cat </option>";
}
}
echo "</select></div>"; 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. it only shows "Please Select Posters Group" by default. the $_GET['CategoryID'] does pass to this page, but not within while { } block. I echo both $_GET['CategoryID'] and $_GET['PosterID'] within while block, they couldn't display. what is the issue?

Comment: so, if you pass correctly the vars at your url but you cannot access them, there is a misconfiguration on your server

Comment: there is no problem to show these two passed Ids on another while loop to bring data for other fields, only has problem within the while loop of category dropdown.  Any idea for my issue? Really need help here. thanks.